# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am learning spring and stuck on this error. I have clean the project, ran maven build which runs build success and refreshed the target but I have still had no luck. Here is the code:

error

```
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring_Project' did not find a matching property.
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.15.0
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.10.3
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/DrewJocham/Documents/practice/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/DrewJocham/Documents/practice/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/DrewJocham/Documents/practice/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/endorsed
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/DrewJocham/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1204 ms
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:32 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:32 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 21 20:49:32 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:32 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/learnspring/config/daoContext.xml]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/learnspring/config/offersService.xml]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 861 ms
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'offers'
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'offers': initialization started
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'offers-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 21 20:49:33 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:33 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/offers-servlet.xml]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'offers-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 21 20:49:33 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'offers-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 21 20:49:33 CEST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'offers': initialization completed in 1209 ms
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4187 ms
Apr 21, 2015 8:49:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/offers/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Spring_Project</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <description>offers</description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<description>Database</description>
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Spring_Tutorial</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/learnspring/config/daoContext.xml
        classpath:com/learnspring/config/offersService.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

daoContext.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.learnspring.datasource.DAO">
    </context:component-scan>
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/Spring_Tutorial" id="dataSource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    </jee:jndi-lookup>
</beans>
```

offersService.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.learnspring.service"> 
</context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

OffersController.java

```
package com.learnspring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.learnspring.datasource.DAO.Offer;
import com.learnspring.service.OffersService;

@Controller
public class OffersController {

    private OffersService offersService;

    //@Autowired
    public void setOffersService(OffersService offersService) {
        this.offersService = offersService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHome(Model model) {

        List<Offer> offers = offersService.getCurrent();

        model.addAttribute("offers", offers);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

OffersService.java

```
package com.learnspring.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.learnspring.datasource.DAO.Offer;
import com.learnspring.datasource.DAO.OfferDAO;

@Service("offersService")
public class OffersService {

    private OfferDAO offerDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setOfferDAO(OfferDAO offerDAO) {
        this.offerDAO = offerDAO;
    }

    public List<Offer> getCurrent() {

        return offerDAO.getOffers();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your context path?

Comment: Have you tried to not map on root (/) ?

Comment: Your controller is not being scanned, you need to include     <context:component-scan base-package="com.learnspring.controller"> in your context configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to register your controller on web.xml by doing:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my opinion you don't need to do that. You can get away with just registering the RequestDispatcher and then as Patrick LC mentioned, have

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.learnspring.controller">
```

take care of scanning your code for controllers to register. Then, it's a matter of setting the request mapping to whatever you want to use. Below I use home.spr, where spr stands for spring, but that's just a convention I use; the important thing is that whatever you choose needs to be declared on the web.xml as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.spr</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then on your controller do:

```
@RequestMapping("/orders/home.spr")
public String getHome(Model model) {

    List<Offer> offers = offersService.getCurrent();

    model.addAttribute("offers", offers);
    return "home";
}
```

Oh...and you might want to try spring.io, it's a bit simpler to work with.

Comment: You forgot to explain why a second `DispatcherServlet` is allegedly needed and what the meaning of the "*.spr" mapping is. OP is trying to learn so suggesting drastic changes without telling why they'd help is not very helpful.

Comment: @kryger Agreed. See revised answer.